# What are the next steps to disassemble this leaky faucet?

Tags: plumbing

The cold water valve on my faucet is leaking, it drips every 5-10 seconds. I’d like to disassemble to see what seals or gaskets need to be replaced, cleaned or serviced.

I got the faucet partially disassembled, but am unsure where to go from here. I removed the spring clip and tried to gently wrench on that large nut shaped part, but it was resistant enough that I didn’t want to force it without being sure I was forcing the right part.

Any advice on next steps?

Links to images. Apparently the upload functionality of the stack exchange iOS app doesn’t work anymore. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuq9w.jpg

Answer (score 1):

First, unsnap that "u" shaped little bracket from the valve stem. Then get a large adjustable wrench or a closed end wrench and loosen and remove that large brass nut from the valve base. Then unscrew the valve stem from the base and replace any washers that are on the end of the valve stem. Check to make sure the stem seat is smooth inside the valve base, if not, then you'll have to replace the seat.

And don't forget to turn off the water supply to the faucet before removing any parts.